# Как скрыть часть текста в input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Если возможно, то желательно без JS

```html
<input name="api-key" value="HGIer532BKe4fGY7b23rx23r">

<!-- Сделать в таком виде, а при фокусе показать полностью -->
<input name="api-key" value="HGI************23r">
```

Comment: Именно часть, или можно весь?

Comment: @Pilaton только часть, менять с типом password не вариант

Answer (score 2):

Фактически конечно можно решить эту задачу без JS но придется немного видоизменить разметку, так для обнаружения мыши можно использовать спобоности ссылок - `:hover`,а для `:after` какой-нибудь контейнер, в данном случае хорошо подходит `span`

Что касается задачи, то я ее не знаю, и вероятно сам бы предпочел делать подобные вещи средствами JS, тем более что для идеального решения только средствами CSS потребуется еще дорабатывать стили, в частности стили выделенного текста, и делать чуть больший охват вокруг input чтобы не было излишнего мерцания.

```css
a:hover span:after{
  display:none;
}

a span:after{
  display: inline-block;
  content: "*****************";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 35px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <span></span>
  <input name="api-key" value="HGIer532BKe4fGY7b23rx23r">
</a>
<!-- Сделать в таком виде, а при фокусе показать полностью -->
<input name="api-key" value="HGI************23r">
```

Answer (score 1):

На **css** (на css думаю не лучший вариант такое делать и надо подстраивать под каждый случай)

```css
.inputRow {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:18px;
}
.inputRow input {
  height:24px;
}
.inputRow span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-table;
  font-size: 18px;
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 22px;
}
.inputRow input:focus + span, .inputRow input:active + span {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputRow" id="pass">
<input name="api-key" value="HGIer532BKe4fGY7b23rx23r">
<span>**************</span>
</div>
```

На **js**

```js
let ak = document.querySelector('input[name=api-key]'),
    oldVal = document.querySelector('input[name=api-key]').value,
    counStar = Math.floor(ak.value.length/100*80),
    start = Math.floor(ak.value.length/100*15),
    starText = ak.value.slice(start,counStar),
    newText = "*".repeat(counStar),
    newVal = ak.value.replace(starText, newText);
    
ak.value = newVal;

ak.onfocus = function() {
ak.value = oldVal;
};

ak.onblur = function() {
ak.value = newVal;
};
```

```html
<input name="api-key" value="HGIer532BKe4fGY7b23rx23r">
```